# ImageMagick Installed, True or False, How to Check? PHP

Tags: php, testing, imagemagick, boolean, gd

I have to run a function that has an option to use GD or ImageMagick - what is the best way (php) to test if ImageMagick is installed, and return a true or false?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use an `if` condition with `extension_loaded()` function to check whether you have the extension is loaded

```
if(extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    echo 'Imagick Loaded';
}
```

[**Documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - i am getting echo 'not installed' in else part ... how to install it ?

Comment: @hitesh http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

Answer (score 0):

Just create an if condition checking for installed extension

```
if (!extension_loaded('imagick')) 
{
    echo 'imagick not installed';
}
else 
{
    echo 'imagick installed'; 
}
```